# Fill gaps with set based on priority

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

**Goal**

For each `Foo` we should try the fill the time frames as much as possible with records from `FooBar`. It's ok to have empty time frames when no records exists in `FooBar`.
The records in `FooBar` behave as a set.
Meaning if `FooId` and the time frame are (exactly) the same the BarId's are all valid in this time frame.
Gaps should be filled based on the sets priority.

**Table structure**

```
CREATE TABLE Foo(
    FooId INT NOT NULL,
    ValidFrom DATETIME NOT NULL,
    ValidUntil DATETIME NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE FooBar (
    FooId INT NOT NULL,
    BarId INT NOT NULL,
    ValidFrom DATETIME NOT NULL,
    ValidUntil DATETIME NOT NULL,
    Priority TINYINT NOT NULL,
)
```

**Sample data**

```
INSERT INTO Foo(FooId, ValidFrom, ValidUntil)
VALUES 
  (1, '2020-01-01', '2021-12-31')
, (2, '2020-01-01', '2021-06-30')

INSERT INTO FooBar(FooId, BarId, ValidFrom, ValidUntil, Priority)
VALUES 
-- First set for FooId = 1 with prio 1
  (1, 1, '2021-01-01', '2021-03-01', 1)
, (1, 2, '2021-01-01', '2021-03-01', 1)
, (1, 3, '2021-01-01', '2021-03-01', 1)
-- Second set for FooId = 1 with prio 2 
, (1, 1, '2021-02-01', '2021-06-01', 2)
, (1, 2, '2021-02-01', '2021-06-01', 2)
-- Third set for FooId = 1 with prio 3
, (1, 1, '2021-01-01', '2021-12-31', 3)
, (1, 2, '2021-01-01', '2021-12-31', 3)
, (1, 3, '2021-01-01', '2021-12-31', 3)
-- Fourth set for FooId = 1 with Prio 1
, (1, 4, '2021-04-01', '2021-04-02', 1)
, (1, 5, '2021-04-01', '2021-04-02', 1)
-- First set for FooId = 2 with prio 3
, (2, 6, '2021-01-01', '2021-04-02', 3)
```

**Expected result**
*Origin column to clarify, shouldn't be part of the generated result set*

| FooId | BarId | ValidFrom | ValidUntil | Origin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-01 | First set |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-01 | First set |
| 1 | 3 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-01 | First set |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-03-02 | 2021-03-31 | Second set |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-03-02 | 2021-03-31 | Second set |
| 1 | 4 | 2021-04-01 | 2021-04-02 | Fourth set |
| 1 | 5 | 2021-04-01 | 2021-04-02 | Fourth set |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-04-03 | 2021-06-01 | Second set |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-04-03 | 2021-06-01 | Second set |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-06-02 | 2021-12-31 | Third set |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-06-02 | 2021-12-31 | Third set |
| 1 | 3 | 2021-06-02 | 2021-12-31 | Third set |
| 2 | 6 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-12-31 | First set (FooId = 2) |

I know this is possible with a cursor or while loop, but I'm looking for a more performant/elegant solution.

Compatibility level is: 130

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the code chosen doesn't answer the question and the input was MODIFIED to add a column which was not in the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's ok to have empty time frames when no records exists in FooBar.

Does this mean that a solution without empty frames is also acceptable?
If so, then the third set for `FooId = 1` also defines a `BarId = 3` for period `2021-03-02 -> 2021-03-31` for example.

**Sample data**

Tweaked the data model a bit to no have those timestamps (`00:00:00.000`) in the result.
Also added a set identifier (`FooBar.SetId`) for easy origin tracing.

```
CREATE TABLE Foo(
    FooId INT NOT NULL,
    ValidFrom DATE/*TIME*/ NOT NULL,
    ValidUntil DATE/*TIME*/ NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE FooBar (
    FooId INT NOT NULL,
    BarId INT NOT NULL,
    ValidFrom DATE/*TIME*/ NOT NULL,
    ValidUntil DATE/*TIME*/ NOT NULL,
    Priority TINYINT NOT NULL,
    SetId nvarchar(5)
)

INSERT INTO Foo(FooId, ValidFrom, ValidUntil)
VALUES 
  (1, '2020-01-01', '2021-12-31')
, (2, '2020-01-01', '2021-06-30')

INSERT INTO FooBar(FooId, BarId, ValidFrom, ValidUntil, Priority, SetId)
VALUES 
-- First set for FooId = 1 with prio 1
  (1, 1, '2021-01-01', '2021-03-01', 1, 'Set 1')
, (1, 2, '2021-01-01', '2021-03-01', 1, 'Set 1')
, (1, 3, '2021-01-01', '2021-03-01', 1, 'Set 1')
-- Second set for FooId = 1 with prio 2 
, (1, 1, '2021-02-01', '2021-06-01', 2, 'Set 2')
, (1, 2, '2021-02-01', '2021-06-01', 2, 'Set 2')
-- Third set for FooId = 1 with prio 3
, (1, 1, '2021-01-01', '2021-12-31', 3, 'Set 3')
, (1, 2, '2021-01-01', '2021-12-31', 3, 'Set 3')
, (1, 3, '2021-01-01', '2021-12-31', 3, 'Set 3')
-- Fourth set for FooId = 1 with Prio 1
, (1, 4, '2021-04-01', '2021-04-02', 1, 'Set 4')
, (1, 5, '2021-04-01', '2021-04-02', 1, 'Set 4')
-- First set for FooId = 2 with prio 3
, (2, 6, '2021-01-01', '2021-04-02', 3, 'Set 1')
```

**Solution**

1. The common table expressions (CTE) `ValidFrom` and `ValidPeriod` cut all period information from `Foo` and `FooBar` in the smallest individual periods.
2. The previous step also produces an extra trailing, incomplete period for each `FooId` that is remove with the `exists` clause.
3. Then for each individual period fetch the `FooBar` record with the first priority value (by saying that no similar record with an even smaller priority is allowed: `not exists ... fb2.Priority < fb.Priority`).

This gives:

```
with ValidFrom as
(
  select f.FooId,
         f.ValidFrom
  from Foo f
    union
  select f.FooId,
         dateadd(day, 1, f.ValidUntil)
  from Foo f
    union
  select fb.FooId,
         fb.ValidFrom
  from FooBar fb
    union
  select fb.FooId,
         dateadd(day, 1, fb.ValidUntil)
  from Foobar fb
),
ValidPeriod as
(
  select vf.FooId,
         vf.ValidFrom,
         dateadd(day, -1, lead(vf.ValidFrom) over(partition by vf.FooId order by vf.ValidFrom)) as ValidUntil
  from ValidFrom vf
)
select vp.FooId,
       fb.BarId,
       vp.ValidFrom,
       vp.ValidUntil,
     --fb.ValidFrom,
     --fb.ValidUntil,
     --fb.Priority,
       fb.SetId
from ValidPeriod vp
left join FooBar fb
  on  fb.FooId = vp.FooId
  and fb.ValidFrom <= vp.ValidUntil
  and fb.ValidUntil >= vp.ValidFrom
  and not exists ( select 'x'
                   from FooBar fb2
                   where fb2.FooId = fb.FooId
                     and fb2.BarId = fb.BarId
                     and fb2.ValidFrom <= vp.ValidUntil
                     and fb2.ValidUntil >= vp.ValidFrom
                     and fb2.Priority < fb.Priority )
where exists ( select 'x'
               from ValidPeriod vp2
               where vp2.FooId = vp.FooId
                 and vp2.ValidFrom > vp.ValidFrom )
order by vp.FooId,
         vp.ValidFrom,
         fb.BarId;
```

**Result**

This result contains more period information than those you requested in your expected result. Removing the `union`'s with `Foo` from the first CTE will remove the `null` values and limit the period to the period information available in `FooBar` alone (in fact this would eliminate `Foo` from the solution entirely).

With `vp.ValidFrom` and `vp.ValidUntil` as result periods:

```
FooId  BarId  ValidFrom   ValidUntil  SetId
-----  -----  ----------  ----------  -----
1      null   2020-01-01  2020-12-31  null  -- extra row
1      1      2021-01-01  2021-01-31  Set 1
1      2      2021-01-01  2021-01-31  Set 1
1      3      2021-01-01  2021-01-31  Set 1
1      1      2021-02-01  2021-03-01  Set 1 -- extra row
1      2      2021-02-01  2021-03-01  Set 1 -- extra row
1      3      2021-02-01  2021-03-01  Set 1 -- extra row
1      1      2021-03-02  2021-03-31  Set 2
1      2      2021-03-02  2021-03-31  Set 2
1      3      2021-03-02  2021-03-31  Set 3 -- extra row
1      1      2021-04-01  2021-04-02  Set 2 -- extra row
1      2      2021-04-01  2021-04-02  Set 2 -- extra row
1      3      2021-04-01  2021-04-02  Set 3 -- extra row
1      4      2021-04-01  2021-04-02  Set 4
1      5      2021-04-01  2021-04-02  Set 4
1      1      2021-04-03  2021-06-01  Set 2
1      2      2021-04-03  2021-06-01  Set 2
1      3      2021-04-03  2021-06-01  Set 3 -- extra row
1      1      2021-06-02  2021-12-31  Set 3
1      2      2021-06-02  2021-12-31  Set 3
1      3      2021-06-02  2021-12-31  Set 3
2      null   2020-01-01  2020-12-31  null  -- extra row
2      6      2021-01-01  2021-04-02  Set 1
2      null   2021-04-03  2021-06-30  null  -- extra row
```

With `fb.ValidFrom` and `fb.ValidUntil` as result periods:

```
FooId  BarId  ValidFrom   ValidUntil  SetId
-----  -----  ----------  ----------  -----
1      null   null        null        null  -- extra row
1      1      2021-01-01  2021-03-01  Set 1
1      2      2021-01-01  2021-03-01  Set 1
1      3      2021-01-01  2021-03-01  Set 1
1      1      2021-01-01  2021-03-01  Set 1 -- extra row
1      2      2021-01-01  2021-03-01  Set 1 -- extra row
1      3      2021-01-01  2021-03-01  Set 1 -- extra row
1      1      2021-02-01  2021-06-01  Set 2
1      2      2021-02-01  2021-06-01  Set 2
1      3      2021-01-01  2021-12-31  Set 3 -- extra row
1      1      2021-02-01  2021-06-01  Set 2 -- extra row
1      2      2021-02-01  2021-06-01  Set 2 -- extra row
1      3      2021-01-01  2021-12-31  Set 3 -- extra row
1      4      2021-04-01  2021-04-02  Set 4
1      5      2021-04-01  2021-04-02  Set 4
1      1      2021-02-01  2021-06-01  Set 2
1      2      2021-02-01  2021-06-01  Set 2
1      3      2021-01-01  2021-12-31  Set 3 -- extra row
1      1      2021-01-01  2021-12-31  Set 3
1      2      2021-01-01  2021-12-31  Set 3
1      3      2021-01-01  2021-12-31  Set 3
2      null   null        null        null  -- extra row
2      6      2021-01-01  2021-04-02  Set 1
2      null   null        null        null  -- extra row
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=b078a453c8b8bf21f857d1ab6a7ef1da) to see things in action.

Comment: This is a very nice starting point, and fast solution. Thanks !